# Touch swipe in meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, touchswipe

Im having trouble integrating meteor and touch swipe. Im using touch swipe to switch between two different tabs and it works for some tabs but for others, Im getting this error. `Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.` Ive seen other questions but im not getting an appropriate answer for my particular project. Im using chrome to debug

Comment: What packages are you using for this?

Comment: @BrendanTurner Im using hedcet:touch-swipe

Comment: [Duplicate issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478267/touch-move-getting-stuck-ignored-attempt-to-cancel-a-touchmove)

Comment: Ive seen that question already. Its simply not working, any ideas?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I guess Ill use hammer js