# how to avoid scroll jumps in android

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have an application with a photo gallery which is presented in one line, and the user can scroll left & right between the images.
When I perform the scrolling I can see (in chrome when I debug the code) in the console the following error:

> Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

This error causes the scroll to jump and not look smooth.

How can I solve this error?
I couldn't find a good answer for this.

UPDATE: it happens only in phonegap. not in mobile web.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that error is the one making the animation work poorly. As far as I saw on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478267/touch-move-getting-stuck-ignored-attempt-to-cancel-a-touchmove), returning true will remove the warning.

Javascript animations on smartphones tend to have worse performance since they aren't hardware accelerated. You can try and find a photo gallery that uses CSS3 transitions, which are hardware-accelerated.

Comment: It is not a real animation. It is just a div with display:flex, and overflow-x: scroll

Comment: Can you post some code? To better understand what the problem can be