# console error ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event

Tags: ionic-framework

I get this error in my ionic app when the user scrolls a `collection-repeat` long list.

> ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

Any idea what this is ?

template:

```
<div class="scrollContainer">
    <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" overflow-scroll="false">

        <div class="loadingboards" ng-if="!transitionFinished">
            <ion-spinner class="spinner spinner-ios">
            </ion-spinner>
            <br/>
            Loading boards list...
        </div>

        <div id="boardselection" ng-if="transitionFinished">
            <ion-item collection-repeat="item in prodataSelect | orderBy:data.sort | filter: data.selectBrand.brand:true | filter: data.selectName.name | unique:'modelStrict'" item-width="96%" item-height="'18%'">

                <a class="optionfuninit item-content" data-proid="{{item.id}}" ng-click="whatToDo(item.id,$event);" ng-class="item.fun == '0' ? 'aNormal' :( item.fun == '1' ? 'aSmallWave' : (item.fun == '2' ? 'aStepUp' : ''))">
                    <img class="imageoptionsbrand" ng-src="{{ imagesUrls[(item.brand | lowercase | nospace)+'.png'] }}" />
                    <div class="listviewTrophy" ng-if="isWinning(item.id)">
                        <i class="icon ion-trophy"></i>
                        <div class="winningboardtext" translate="computepage.30">Winning Board</div>
                    </div>
                    <i class="icon ion-female" ng-show="item.gender == 'female'"></i>
                    <div class="listviewtexts" ng-class="item.fun == '0' ? 'aNormal' :( item.fun == '1' ? 'aSmallWave' : (item.fun == '2' ? 'aStepUp' : ''))">
                        <span class="listviewtextsmodel">{{item.modelStrict}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imagebox rotate90rightCenter">
                        <img class="imageoptionsmodel " ng-src="{{imagesUrls[item.imageName]}}" />
                    </div>
                </a>

            </ion-item>
        </div>

    </ion-scroll>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/26478267/2003702 ?

Comment: yes but it doesn't seem to be the same issue

Comment: Can you then please share some code or you'll never get an answer.

Comment: I would, but what part of the code ?

Comment: Where the collection-repeat list is and maybe the controller that is in use on that view?

Comment: ok I am adding the template code but I think the controller file is too big to add here

Comment: I am stuck at the same place..does anyone know the solution ?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Have you had any progress on this?

Comment: can you please add the method that loads the list in prodataSelect?

Answer (score -1):

It worked to me to comment these lines in the file vendor.js

```
ToggleGesture.prototype.onDragStart = function (ev) {
    /*ev.preventDefault();*/
    this.toggle._onDragStart(Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__util_dom__["f" /* pointerCoord */])(ev).x);
};
ToggleGesture.prototype.onDragMove = function (ev) {
    /*ev.preventDefault();*/
    this.toggle._onDragMove(Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__util_dom__["f" /* pointerCoord */])(ev).x);
};
ToggleGesture.prototype.onDragEnd = function (ev) {
    /*ev.preventDefault();*/
    this.toggle._onDragEnd(Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__util_dom__["f" /* pointerCoord */])(ev).x);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to `ion-datetime 3-ios.entry.js` and comment the line 1383:

```
detail.event.preventDefault();
```

You will get rid of the error:

> [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted