# How to fix [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events, mousedown, touchstart

I want to handle 'touchstart' event for my mobile site. It worked fine, but now it causes an error in the console.

I tested it with my Galaxi S7 Chrome v72.0 browser, and inspected it with `chrome://inspect/#devices` extension.

And when I tried touch it causes:

> [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

I think problem is actual only for Chrome v72.0 browser.

```
    var container = document.getElementById('container'),
        fragments = document.createDocumentFragment(),           
        touchScreen = document.createElement('div');

    fragments.appendChild(touchScreen);
    container.appendChild(fragments);

    var mousedownF = function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      /* Do something */
      return false;
   };

   touchScreen.addEventListener('touchstart', mousedownF);
   touchScreen.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedownF);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Touch move getting stuck Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478267/touch-move-getting-stuck-ignored-attempt-to-cancel-a-touchmove)

Comment: I tryed 
```
if (e.cancelable) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
``` 
but not working.

Comment: Answers didn't help me.

Comment: Any updates? I'm having the same issue. Please share with use if you found solution